# How to target value of a checkbox inside a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is the code -

```
<div class="filter-box" id="categoryFilter">             
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Education" value="3">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="12" name="Employment" value="12">
    <label for="Employment">Employment</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Goods and Services" value="5">
    <label for="Goods and Services">Goods and Services</label>
</div>
```

I need to target the value or the ID of the checkbox clicked so I can add it to the URL string of an API call.

How can I target the checkbox so that I can write an on click event that returns the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Label's `for` should match the `id`, not the Input's `name`
- Don't overuse numeric IDs, there's a great chance at some point your IDs will duplicate and collide. Rather, remove the `id` and `for` attribute and wrap your inputs into the `<label>`
- Use jQuery's "change" event function callback
- Use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the desired property value

```js
$("#categoryFilter").on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
  const name = $(this).prop("name");
  const value = $(this).prop("value");
  const checked = $(this).prop("checked");
  console.log(`${name} ${value} ${checked}`);
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-box" id="categoryFilter">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Education" value="3">
    Education
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Employment" value="12">
    Employment
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Goods and Services" value="5">
    Goods and Services
  </label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With the death of IE browsers, and evergreen browsers keeping pace with the newest ECMAScript goodies, jQuery is not necessary nowadays. A pure JavaScript approach, without the overhead of a library like jQuery would be:

```js
document.querySelector("#categoryFilter").addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  const el = evt.target.closest("[type=checkbox]");
  if ( !el ) return; // Not a checkbox
  console.log(`${el.name} ${el.value} ${el.checked}`);
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-box" id="categoryFilter">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Education" value="3">
    Education
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Employment" value="12">
    Employment
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Goods and Services" value="5">
    Goods and Services
  </label>
</div>
```

Notice also, the above example in pure JavaScript uses [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), similar to what you would do in jQuery with `$(parent).on("eventName", "dynamicChild", fn)` - which will  work even for dynamically created checkbox elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener on the containing `<div>` element for the change event. Then, you can get the `value` from the event's target.

```js
document.querySelector('#categoryFilter').addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.checked, e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="filter-box" id="categoryFilter">             
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Education" value="3">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="12" name="Employment" value="12">
    <label for="Employment">Employment</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Goods and Services" value="5">
    <label for="Goods and Services">Goods and Services</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should check that e.target is an in input[type="checkbox"], if it is a label this won't work. Also I think the question was how to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#categoryFilter').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
  let me = $(this);
  let checkboxName = me.attr('name');
  let checked = me.prop('checked'); // true/false
  console.log(`The checkbox ${checkboxName} was ${checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this solution,  you have to use forEach and each loop functions then applying onchange event on them to get their value and ID

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach(function(element){
        element.addEventListener("change",function(e){
            console.log("TARGET VALUE "+e.target.value)
            console.log("ID: "+element.getAttribute("id"))
        })
    })

    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i,e){
        $(e).change(function(evt){
            console.log("FROM JQUERY VALUE "+$(this).val())
            console.log("FROM JQUERY ID "+$(this).prop('id'))
        })
    })
```